# Socrata: How do I add the $order clause to a query?

Tags: android, sorting, socrata

I'm working a small Android project for a class. 
In it, I'm building a query against an open Socrata dataset in Los Angeles.

Here's the URL:
https://data.lacity.org/resource/yv23-pmwf.json?%24select=zip_code%2Cissue_date%2Caddress_start%2Caddress_end%2Cstreet_name%2Cstreet_suffix%2Cwork_description%2Cvaluation&%24where=issue_date%3E%3D%272015-02-25T00%3A00%3A00%27%20AND%20zip_code%3D90291

This works.

But I can't figure out what the addition is that would 'order' the result.
The Socrata documentation says this:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~The $order Parameter~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The $order parameter determines how the results should be sorted, using the values from the specified columns, similar to a SQL ORDER BY. Sorting can be performed in either ascending or descending order, the default being ascending, but you can also reverse the order with DESC.

For example, to sort our earthquakes by magnitude, in descending order:

https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv?$order=magnitude DESC

We could sort them in ascending order by replacing DESC with ASC, or by simply omitting it.
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I've tried various combinations of &$, $&, just &, just $, to append
"order=issue_date DESC" to the URL's query.

A plain '&' results in 
"code" : "query.compiler.malformed",
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "Error, could not parse SoQL query ......."
and a complete listing of the rest of the URL

An '&$' seems moderately better. I only get the error:
"error" : true,
  "message" : "Unrecognized arguments [$order=issue_date DESC]"

I've also tried a '+' between issue_date and DESC, or not including the 'DESC', but I just get the 'Unrecognized arguments [ whatever I typed ]

Note to Socrata's Technical writers: None of your examples demonstrate building actual queries, with multiple parameters. A few wouldn't hurt.

Also, hurl-it was useless: I built a multi-param query there, which does what I'd like (but on their sample set), except it puts the $order up front, before the $select, and displays the resulting URL as follows:

https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv?$order=magnitude

DESC&$select=location, magnitude

So I have no idea how the DESC direction of the $order is attached to that clause. Played with it a while, but never figured it out.

Anyone out there familiar with this SoQL?

I found Socrata's Android API library, but I'm still new to Android, as well as Socrata, and thought I'd put that off for a while. Just need this one query. Maybe I should have spent the last two hours trying to figure that out instead of this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are having an issue with the $order clause. If I take your query (decoded for readability) I just attach the order clause as &$order=issue_date DESC. So here is the complete query which works fine for me:

```
https://data.lacity.org/resource/yv23-pmwf.json?$select=zip_code,issue_date,address_start,address_end,street_name,street_suffix,work_description,valuation&$where=issue_date>='2015-02-25T00:00:00' AND zip_code=90291&$order=issue_date DESC
```

Perhaps you are URL-encoding things incorrectly? Another thing to note is you can attach the $order clause as a standard URL parameter anywhere in your query string.